# Unable install cmake and ccmake?

Tags: 12.10, apt, software-installation, ppa, cmake

So the thing is I'm trying to install Cmake and cmake-curses-gui. 
I have updated the system with `apt-get-update`.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake   
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done   
Package cmake is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'cmake' has no installation candidate

sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui   
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done   
E: Unable to locate package cmake-curses-gui
```

That's strange. Can anyone give some pointers?

Pastbin sources.list :- http://pastebin.com/DufycYfZ

Comment: cmake is in the repositories, I suggest you run `sudo apt-get update` first.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I did that before many times. But still the same output. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having same issue, what other source? http://i.tylerwhitney.com/image/1E1w260X2w2u

Comment: @user159618 What is the result of `apt-cache policy cmake cmake-curses-gui`?

Comment: You mention `apt-get-update`  I hope it just typo mistake in the question. It should be `apt-get update` or just use update manage graphic interface.